# how to save pytorch model?

Tags: python, pytorch, resnet

I use pytorch's resnet model

I am participating in a Kaggle competition with a very large data set!
The accuracy percentage I get in train, val is about 80%.
But in the test I get a very low accuracy percentage - 5% accuracy.

I thought it might be useful to save the model after training and then train the model again (but with a trained model) and finally use the trained model for the test set

How can the model be saved and used?
I saw that there are 2 methods. Which one is relevant for my case?

Answer (score 0):

Your validation is giving 80% and Test is giving 5%?
I think your validation set doesn't contain all the variety of data a test set contains. Validation set shouldn't be same as Testing set, but getting 5% in testing  might mean your training set contains data that amounts to 5% of variety that testing set contains for which it was trained.
I think you should start with getting a better training set, validation set.

80% in validation is not enough training of the model. In most training I do, results are not good enough until the validation set give 99% in accuracy and sometimes even that is not sufficient.